# Comparing residuals in two regression models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, estimation, linear-model, convergence

Let us have two linear models. Let $\alpha_i$ be real numbers same in both.

$$
LM1:  Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1X_1+\alpha_2X_2 + \varepsilon
$$

$$
LM2:  Y^\prime=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1X^\prime_1+\alpha_2X^\prime_2 + \varepsilon`
$$

The difference between them is only in the fact that $X_i, X^\prime_i$ are different. Now, I want to test a hypothesis that the noise distribution remains the same $H_0: \varepsilon\overset{D}{=}\varepsilon`$ (we assume noise has a zero mean and finite variance). We have available random samples, from the first one of length $n$: $(Y_1, X_1)^\top, \dots, (Y_{n}, X_{n})^\top$, and from the second one with length $m$:  $(Y`_1, X`_1)^\top, \dots, (Y`_{m}, X`_{m})^\top$.

**My approach:**  Based on these samples, we estimate $\hat{\alpha_i},\hat{\alpha_i}^\prime $ where e.g. $\hat{\alpha_i}^\prime$ is the estimation using LSE from the LM2.
Now, compute the residuals. So $\hat{\varepsilon}=Y-\hat{\alpha_0}-\hat{\alpha_1}X_1 - \hat{\alpha_2}X_2$ and similarly for the second model $\hat{\varepsilon}^\prime$.

Asymptotically  $\hat{\varepsilon}\overset{D}{=}\hat{\varepsilon}^\prime$, as $n,m\to\infty$ because estimates of the coefficients are consistent. BUT, for finite $n$, we did not converge yet to these limits. If I do e.g. KStest ($ks.test(rez1, rez2)$), it will reject this hypothesis too often even if it is true. Is it a correct test at least asymptotically? Do you know about some other test comparing these distributions with a proper $p-$ value?

My interest is more academic and I want a test that provably works.

Here is also some idea of the sample code I used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
```

n=1e+04
f <- function(X1, X2){return(-1 + 1*X1 + 2*X2)}

X11=rnorm(n, 0,1);X12=rnorm(n, -1, 2)
Y1= f(X11, X12) + rLaplace(n)

fit=lm(Y1~X11+X12, data= data.frame(Y1, X11, X12))
rez1=fit$residuals

X21=rexp(n, 1);X22=rexp(n,2)
Y2= f(X21, X22) + rLaplace(n)

fit2=lm(Y2~X21+X22, data= data.frame(Y2, X21, X22))
rez2=fit2$residuals

ks.test(rez1, rez2))

```
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sceptical of your statement about the KS test.  How have you tried to apply it?  How did you determine its false positive rate in this situation? The concern here is whether you truly want to test for identity of *distribution* or only want to compare some properties of the distributions, such as their variances.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Ok, here is what I did: generate $Y=1+10*X_1+20*X_2+\varepsilon$ for some random $X_1, X_2, \varepsilon$. Compute $rez1=lm(Y\sim X_1+X_2)\$residuals$.  Do the same thing with different $X_1, X_2$ and finally test $ks.test(rez1, rez2)$. This will reject more than once in every 20generations.

Comment: Thank you: I see what you mean.  There are several problematic aspects of this approach that make *any* distributional test inapplicable.  First is that the residuals within one model are not independent; the second is that they are guaranteed to have a mean of zero.  The first becomes a non-issue as the dataset grows large, but the second is critical.  If instead of doing any regression you simply were to generate the $X_i$ independently with a common continuous distribution and run `ks.test(x1-mean(x1), x2-mean(x2))` you would experience identical problems.

Comment: The crux of the matter is that by forcing the means to be equal, you make the two sets of values look more similar to each other than would occur in two independent random samples from a common distribution.  What ultimately rescues us is that it's neither necessary nor advisable to conduct a formal distributional test of residuals, making this problem purely academic (although certainly an interesting one).

Comment: I see and fully agree with the mean problem. I added the fact that we assume the mean to be zero. It is interesting that because of this, residuals will be centred around zero "more" than actual starting random samples. 

Considering your first problem- yes, residuals are dependent but with decreasing dependence as $n\to\infty$. But I don't know if it means that the test will be bad or not (asymptotically). 

And yes, it is a purely academic problem, I am only trying to prove that it works (and I am using it as a part of a different research problem), or find some better test.

Comment: The assumption makes no difference. In any least squares model that includes an intercept, the mean of the residuals is guaranteed to be zero by construction.

Comment: Yes, I see (although if the noises differ only as a shift, we wouldn't observe this in residuals (it would only change $\alpha_0$)). But anyway, I don't see why is it a bad thing- it should "correctly not reject" more often, but asymptotically it is still neglicable.

Comment: Can we assume that $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^\prime$ are both Gaussian? If not, can we assume they're from the same (location-scale) family of distributions?

Comment: We can not assume Gaussianity, unfortunately. But most of the time, we are interested in results when they are the same (which we assume under the null hypothesis). Under alternative, they can be basically anything with finite variance

Comment: So $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^\prime$ can have any distributions? They don't have to be in the same family (i.e. both t-distributions, cauchy distributions, gamma distributions)? We could have, for example, $\epsilon \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ and $\epsilon^\prime \sim Cauchy(\eta, \gamma)$?

Comment: hmm. I guess we can assume continuity and full support on R. And not Cauchy(1,1) because it does not have finite variance.

Comment: But no, actually in the research, they are used to model "hidden covariates", where we do not really impose any restrictions on the distribution of covariates. But if it helps, I am definitely interested even if they lie in the same family (and even on X you can assume something "reasonable" if you want), it would still help

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate the problem from the question with the code below. The discrepancy between the distribution of the test statistic and the Kolmogorov distribution can be changed by manipulating the fit. If we use an intercept `lm(Y~1+X1+X2)$residuals` then the difference is largest.

- Without intercept, the difference is only small

[image: no intercept]

- With intercept, the difference is large

[image: with intercept]

#### The case with only an intercept

We get the discrepancy already when we use *only* an intercept, ie. if we would model `lm(Y~1)$residuals`.

The discrepancy due to the intercept is easier to understand. The sampling of residuals is *not* independently drawing from a distribution for the residuals. Instead, the residuals will be correlated (the same is true for the case without intercept, but less strong).

This is most easy to see for the case of a sample of size 2 that is being modeled by only an intercept. The residuals will equal $\pm |x_1-x_2|$ and are symmetric.

More generally, for larger $n$, the residuals can be equated as

$$r_i = \epsilon_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j $$

This makes the residuals multivariate normal distributed, if the $\epsilon$ are normal distributed. If we consider $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ then the covariance matrix for the $r_i$ is

$$
\Sigma_{ij} = \begin{cases} \frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}  & \quad \text{if $i=j$}\\
 -\frac{n-1}{n^2}  & \quad \text{if $i \neq j$}
\end{cases}
$$

We can obtain the same result by sampling from a multivariate normal distribution with this correlation. In the code below we did this with the function `sim2` which produces the following image

#### Intuitively, what's happening?

The Kolmogornov Smirnoff test compares the deviation of the empirical distribution function. Let's focus on this distribution in a single point, at zero.

**The error terms**, if they are distributed as a standard normal distribution, then they will have fifty-fifty probability to be above or below the point zero. The empirical distribution in the point zero will follow a binomial distribution with $n$ trials and $p=0.5$.

**The residual terms** will be different. The residual terms are transformed error terms.

The fit with an intercept will shift the terms up or down. If there are many error terms above zero then a mean above zero is more likely and a shift down will be more likely. If there are many error terms below zero then a mean below zero is more likely and a shift up will be more likely.

So in comparison to the error terms, the residual terms will have a smaller variation for the empirical distribution in the point zero.

#### R-code

```r
### function to simulate data 
### and compute test statistic for KS test
sim = function(n = 100, plot = "n") {
  X1 = rnorm(n)
  X2 = rnorm(n)
  Y = rnorm(n) 
  R1 = lm(Y~0+X1+X2)$residuals

  # use these alternatives below to get the clearest discrepancy
  #R1 = lm(Y~1+X1+X2)$residuals
  #R1 = lm(Y~1)$residuals

  X1 = rnorm(n)
  X2 = rnorm(n)
  Y = rnorm(n) 
  R2 = lm(Y~0+X1+X2)$residuals

  # use these alternatives below to get the clearest discrepancy
  #R2 = lm(Y~1+X1+X2)$residuals
  #R2 = lm(Y~1)$residuals
  
  if (plot == "y") {
    plot(R1[order(R1)],1:n, type ="l")
    lines(R2[order(R2)],1:n, col = 2)
  }
  test = ks.test(R1,R2)
  return(test$statistic)
}



### function to simulate data using multivariate normal
sim2 = function(n = 100, plot = "n") {
  ### create covariance matrix for mvrnorm distribution
  Sig = matrix(-(n-1)/n^2,n,n)
  diag(Sig) <- rep((n-1)^2/n^2,n)
  
  R1 = MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu = rep(0,n), Sigma = Sig)
  R2 = MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu = rep(0,n), Sigma = Sig)
  
  if (plot == "y") {
    plot(R1[order(R1)],1:n, type ="l")
    lines(R2[order(R2)],1:n, col = 2)
  }
  test = ks.test(R1,R2)
  return(test$statistic)
}

### perform 10^3 simulations and plot histogram
set.seed(1)
n = 600
D = replicate(10^4,sim(n))

br = seq(0,max(D)+d,1/n)*sqrt(n/2)
hist(sqrt(n/2)*D, breaks = br, freq = 0)

### function to compute kolmogorov distribution
pkolm = function(x) {
  k = 1:100
  sqrt(2*pi)/x*sum( exp(-(2*k-1)^2*pi^2/(8*x^2)) )
}
pkolm = Vectorize(pkolm)

### add kolmogorov distribution to histogram
P = c(pkolm(br))
P[1] = 0
points(br[-1]-br[2]/2, diff(P)/br[2])
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I had a "no internet" holiday. And thanks for the response. As for the context: I agree with what you wrote. Sure, residuals are dependent with correlation going to 0 as $n\to\infty$, and will be shifted in some direction (even in only the intercept case), but again, consistent as $n\to\infty$. However, I don't really understand the the conclusion- so is testing by ks.test(rez1,rez2) wrong? You say that residuals will have smaller variation as the error terms. That should even shift for more stronger test statistic, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlbertParadek Yes, the conclusion is that it is wrong.

Comment: Would it help If I compute an estimate for the distribution in the intuitive example case, which considered only the statistic for the difference between the empirical distributions in a single point on the distribution curve rather than the entire curve (the latter, entire curve/distribution comparison, is the KS test)? This example case is easier because the statistic in the ideal situation follows a binomial distribution. But, the discrepancy is very similar as what we would get with the KS test.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still trying to understand what you are doing- I feel like I don't really comprehend the point. So you are taking only the case when $Y=c+\epsilon$ and comparing $Y-\hat{c}$?

Comment: @AlbertParadek I am comparing two samples of residuals as if the individual residuals in a sample are iid distributed. But, because this independency condition is violated (which happens especially due to the intercept) we get a discrepancy when we compute the KS statistic. What I explain in the answer is not for the KS statistic, which is the largest difference between the two empirical distributions, but for the simpler difference between the two empirical distributions in the point zero (which doesn't follow the Kolmogornov distribution but the simpler binomial distribution).

Comment: @albertparadek *"So you are taking only the case when $Y=c+\epsilon$ and comparing $Y−\hat{c}$?"* Yes, this simpler situation is sufficient to replicate the problem from your question. Effectively we have two samples of random numbers $\epsilon_i$ from which we compute residuals $r_i = \epsilon_i - \bar{\epsilon}_i$. The KS statistic and the Kolmogorov distribution work for the comparison of the empirical distributions based on the $\epsilon_i$, but not for the empirical distributions based on the $r_i$.